# Execute TimeFold QuickStart School TimeTabling from DemoResource to JSON source

Tags: java, timefold

I wanted to ask for an explanation on how to switch from running the DEMO Resource when I run Timefold quickstart school timetabling with Apache Maven on localhost to inserting a Json by hand and having the code work on tabbing execution.

I don't understand if it's just a matter of running or I have to go and edit something in source or html to make sure that the localhost doesn't just get the example of the TimeTableDemoResource class

Answer (score 0):

The quickstarts are just examples of how you would integrate Timefold Solver in a web app. They are starter points, they aren't expected to be complete and they are not set in stone; you can modify the code in any way that you like.

In reality, you will have all sorts of requirements for your frontend, and for your backend. It is your responsibility to transform those requirements into code, assuming you have the skills necessary to write frontend and backend code.